# Accumulator not reset between 2 consecutive calls to R.reduce in a R.pipe

Tags: ramda.js

Considering this code, using Ramda 0.21.0:

```
var iteratee = (acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = ++v;
  return acc
}

var foo = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.reduce(iteratee, {})
)

console.log(foo({ a: 1, b: 2})) // { a: 2, b: 3 }
console.log(foo({ c: 3, d: 4})) // { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 }
```

Why does the second call to `foo` display `{ a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 }` instead of `{ c: 4, d: 5 }`?

Is there some kind of memoization going on? I would expect the initial value of `acc` to be reset to `{}` each time foo is applied.

Comment: You mutate initial value. Ramda doesn't care about it, and doesn't make a clone at begin of iterating

Comment: Also your example can be done with map function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer mostly expands on the comments by [@iofjuupasli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761484)

The problem is the mutation of the accumulator object.  You create one in the definition of `foo` which is reused on every call, and then you update it in `iteratee` (horrible name, IMHO.  Call it `bar` or something.  :-) ).  There are several ways you could fix this.  One might be to make sure that you pass a new accumulator on each call to `foo`:

```
var iteratee = (acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] = ++v;
  return acc
}

var foo = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  list => R.reduce(iteratee, {}, list)
)

foo({ a: 1, b: 2}); //=> {"a": 2, "b": 3}
foo({ c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {"c": 4, "d": 5}
```

This works, but feels unsatisfying.  Perhaps more helpful would be to avoid mutating the accumulator object on each pass.  [`assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) will create a new object that reuses as much of the previous one as possible:

```
var iteratee = (acc, [k, v]) => R.assoc(k, v + 1, acc)

var foo = R.pipe(
  R.toPairs,
  R.reduce(iteratee, {})
);

foo({ a: 1, b: 2}); //=> {"a": 2, "b": 3}
foo({ c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {"c": 4, "d": 5}
```

This seems cleaner.  But in fact Ramda has a much simpler solution.  The [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) function treats objects as functors to be mapped over.  Combining this with [`inc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#inc), which simply increments a value, we can just do this:

```
var foo = R.map(R.inc);

foo({ a: 1, b: 2}); //=> {"a": 2, "b": 3}
foo({ c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {"c": 4, "d": 5}
```

And that feels really clean!

Comment: Why does `reduce` reuse the same accumulator across different calls? It doesn't make sense to me, since the purpose of being able to compose functions is to reuse them.

Comment: `reduce` uses the accumulator you pass to it.   In this case the user was reusing the same reference on every call *and* mutating it in the iteration step.   That combination can be deadly... but if Ramda were to clone the reference used on each invocation -- the only other option -- then users who *wanted* `reduce` to mutate the accumulator supplied couldn't get that behaviour.  I don't see any other palatable options.   Do you?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the explanation.